# Cannot connect to a classic VM just created in Azure portal

Tags: virtual-machines, connection

Up to now, we have always used the classic Azure portal to create new classic VM instances for updating our RemoteApp.

As we only have small adjusments to do, we create the new classic VW on the foundation of the last image used to create the RemoteApp.
Today, when the new VM is ready for connection, each time we try to connect we get the following message :

"La session distante a été déconnectée, car aucun serveur de licences Bureau à distance n'est disponible pour fournir une licence. Prenez contact avec l'administrateur du serveur."  ("The remote session was disconnected because no Remote Desktop license server available to provide a license. Please contact the server administrator.")

We have the same problem when working from the new portal and also when creating a classic VM from scratch (not on the base of the previous image)
So, for the moment we cannot update our RemoteApp service.
Thank you to anybody who will give us an advice to solve that issue.
Christophe

Comment: `"La session distante a été déconnectée, car aucun serveur de licences Bureau à distance n'est disponible pour fournir une licence. Prenez contact avec l'administrateur du serveur."` - Please repost that in English. Thanks.